# GetOverlappedResult(bWait=TRUE) vs WaitForSingleObject() for overlapped I/O

Tags: c, windows, winapi

When I open and read file in OVERLAPPED manner on Win32 api, I then have several ways to complete IO request including waiting for file handle (or event in overlapped structure) using

- `WaitForSingleObject`
- `GetOverlappedResult` with bWait=TRUE

Both functions seems to have same effect: thread stopped until handle or event is signaled, and that means data is placed in buffer provided to `ReadFile`.

So, what is the difference? Why do I need `GetOverlappedResult`?

Comment: Short version: `WaitForSingleObject` won't tell you whether the operation succeeded or failed, and if it happens to be the kind of I/O that might process fewer bytes than you asked it to, you won't know that either.

Answer (score 5):

i full agree with *Remus Rusanu* [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42742085/6401656) . also instead create own *IOCP* and thread pool, which will be listen on this *IOCP*, you can use or [`BindIoCompletionCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363484(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`CreateThreadpoolIo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682464(v=vs.85).aspx) (begin from vista) - in this case system yourself create *IOCP* and thread pool wich will be listen on this *IOCP* and when some operation completed - call your callback. this is very simplify code vs own iocp/thread pool (*own iocp/thread pool really i think have sense implement only when you have very big count I/O (say socket io on server side) and need special optimization for perfomance*)

however

> So, what is the difference? Why do I need GetOverlappedResult

how you can see `GetOverlappedResult[Ex]` not only wait for result, but

- return to you *NumberOfBytesTransferred* if operation is completed.
- if operation is completed with error *NTSTATUS* - convert it to win32
  error and set last error
- if operation still pending and you want wait - it select wait on
  *hFile* or *hEvent*

so `GetOverlappedResult[Ex]` do much more than simply call `WaitForSingleObject`

however not very hard implement this API yourself. for example

```
BOOL
WINAPI
MyGetOverlappedResult(
                    _In_ HANDLE hFile,
                    _In_ LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped,
                    _Out_ LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesTransferred,
                    _In_ BOOL bWait
                    )
{
    if ((NTSTATUS)lpOverlapped->Internal == STATUS_PENDING)
    {
        if (!bWait)
        {
            SetLastError(ERROR_IO_INCOMPLETE);
            return FALSE;
        }

        if (lpOverlapped->hEvent)
        {
            hFile = lpOverlapped->hEvent;
        }

        if (WaitForSingleObject(hFile, INFINITE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MemoryBarrier();
    }

    *lpNumberOfBytesTransferred = (ULONG)lpOverlapped->InternalHigh;
    NTSTATUS status = (NTSTATUS)lpOverlapped->Internal;
    if (status)
    {
        RtlNtStatusToDosError(status);
    }
    return NT_SUCCESS(status);
}
```

so what better : use `GetOverlappedResult[Ex]` or implement it functional yourself ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use either, but truly that's not the 'right' way of doing it. you should attach the handle to an IO completion port and then wait on the completion port. This way you have one pool of threads servicing many IO events, as you can attach multiple handles to a completion port. I recommend reading [Designing Applications for High Performance](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/winserverperformance/2008/04/25/designing-applications-for-high-performance-part-1/).

Comment: Thank you, but I will never have more than 2 I/O operations, so I am not sure I need IO Completion ports. I am aware about them and about other approaches like Alterable IO (APC).  My question was about the difference:)

Comment: @user996142 use  IO Completion ports always better than wait with `GetOverlappedResult` for *any count* if I/O operations, also you can use it indirect by [BindIoCompletionCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363484(v=vs.85).aspx) or [CreateThreadpoolIo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682464(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @RbMm in the general case, I agree 100% that IOCP will be better than overlapped IO.  The one exception to that which I am aware of is full duplex serial IO.  According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx in the "Reading and Writing" section, "Non-Overlapped IO" subsection, it notes that full duplex communication is not possible on a serial port without using overlapped IO.

Comment: @dgnuff - *IOCP will be better than overlapped IO* - *overlapped I/O* - this is *asynchronous I/O*. mean that file handle open in asynchronous mode - with flag `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` (if we use `CreateFile`) or without `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_[NON]ALERT` flags if we use *Zw* api. the `IOCP` can be associated with file handle only in case it is [asynchronous](https://github.com/Zer0Mem0ry/ntoskrnl/blob/master/Io/iomgr/qsinfo.c#L1539) (look 1550 line). so your comment is incorrect. IOCP not io type. this is another. and can be used only with overlapped IO