# GetOverlappedResult when ReadFile returns true

Tags: winapi

Can I use `GetOverlappedResult` to return the number of bytes read if `ReadFile` with `OVERLAPPED` IO returned `true` (meaning the result was never pending?)

Comment: C != C++. Tag only with the language that you're using, unless both are actually relevant.

Comment: I am using win32 APIs in C++ but win32 can be used in C as well so C and C++ is appropriate.

Comment: But you aren't using C, are you? No need to tag with it then, unless there's a problem with the C++→C functions calls.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: The MSDN article for GetOverlappedResult() specifically states that this is not valid.  YMMV if you try this anyway, you'll take a dependency on driver behavior.

Comment: No language tag required here at all. The question concerns the API which is language agnostic.

Comment: yes, of course can

Comment: @HansPassant - you mistake - call `GetOverlappedResult` absolute valid and correct in this case. and return correct data. if because `ReadFile` return true - operation already completed (no `STATUS_PENDING` in `OVERLAPPED` ) and function return `Information`

Comment: It has to work, because the [ReadFile docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile) states for OVERLAPPED IO: `The lpNumberOfBytesRead parameter should be set to NULL. Use the GetOverlappedResult function to get the actual number of bytes read`

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: Are you suggesting to try it on 7 different windows versions, with 72 different service pack levels, thousands of different combinations of security updates, and then still have it fail on a future update because you didn't follow the documentation?  "Just try it" is not an acceptable approach to use of an API.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I was curious what results the OP was getting and thought it would be good supporting information.

Comment: [The Old New Thing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140206-00/?p=1853) agrees as well: `The Get­Overlapped­Result/Ex function can be used to wait on an I/O that has already completed`

Answer (score 1):

yes. you can call `GetOverlappedResult` in this case.

in your concrete case, if `ReadFile` return `true`, mean that io operation already completed. the `GetOverlappedResult` from self side first of all check [`IO_STATUS_BLOCK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ns-wdm-_io_status_block) at begin of [`OVERLAPPED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-_overlapped) . more concrete checked `Internal` (`NTSTATUS Status`) for `STATUS_PENDING`

> The status code for the I/O request. When the request is issued, the
>   system sets this member to `STATUS_PENDING` to indicate that the
>   operation has not yet started. When the request is completed, the
>   system sets this member to the status code for the completed request.

if here **not** `STATUS_PENDING` (`Status != STATUS_PENDING`) `GetOverlappedResult` understand that io already completed. if it error status (`Status < 0`) convert it to win32 error and set last error, otherwise read `InternalHigh` (*The number of bytes transferred for the I/O request. The system sets this member if the request is completed without errors.*)  and copy it to `*lpNumberOfBytesTransferred`.

so in your case - `Status != STATUS_PENDING` and `Status >= 0` (because `ReadFile` return `true`) - and `GetOverlappedResult` just return `true` to you and set `*lpNumberOfBytesTransferred = (DWORD)lpOverlapped->InternalHigh`

Comment: @zett42 - what concrete information you mean ? but all what i wrote here enough well known and simply

Comment: Sounds plausible but if possible can you point me to some canonical document?

Comment: @zett42 - i dont know any formal documents where this described. what i wrote based on my knowledge about i/o request in windows, (IRP* processing and completion, nt-api and how win32 api call nt. also can look for code of [`GetOverlappedResult`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42742598/6401656) at almost equal real src code of this routine. all i/o nt api use `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` pointer. in `IRP` also exist pointer to user iosb and when io (IRP or fast io) complete - io manager write back final operation status to iosb. `overlapped` is shell over iosb

Comment: @zett42 - not hard understand how `GetOverlappedResult` must work - if simply check `IO_STATUS_BLOCK.Status` for `STATUS_PENDING` - are io complete ? if yes (here any another value) - simply read `Information` (byte count) convert status to win32 error and return. if io yet not completed and not wit - set last error to `ERROR_IO_INCOMPLETE` and exit. if user want wait - wait on event from overlapped if it not 0 (io manager in kernel set this event when io completed). if no event - waut direct on file object, but this is bad and can give wrong result in case multiple io in concurent.

Comment: @doron really every io must have unique hEvent (if we use event completion). `GetOverlappedResult` designed exactly for io used `hEvent`. not for apc or iocp

Comment: Microsoft reserves the right to change things in the kernel so unless they promise to maintain some behaviour, don't bet your life on it, some service pack might break everything.

Comment: @doron - no, here will be nothing break. this is fundamental thing. `ReadFile` call `NtReadFile`, `OVERLAPPED` is placeholder for `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` which is mandatory for any io operation. system write final status to iosb. if always can check this status if api return true

Answer (score -2):

If the operation completes synchronously you cannot use use `GetOverlappedResult` to query the result or the bytes read.

> If, on the other hand, an operation is completed immediately, then `&NumberOfBytesRead` passed into `ReadFile` is valid for the number of bytes read. In this case, ignore the `OVERLAPPED` structure passed into `ReadFile`; do not use it with `GetOverlappedResult` or `WaitForSingleObject`.

See https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/156932/asynchronous-disk-i-o-appears-as-synchronous-on-windows for details.

Comment: this is absolute false. from what you decide this ? absolute no matter synchronous or not complete operation. we always can use `GetOverlappedResult`

Comment: *ignore the OVERLAPPED structure passed into ReadFile; do not use it with GetOverlappedResult or WaitForSingleObject.* not mean that we can not use it. this mean that this is senseless for this code fragment - we already have `NumberOfBytesRead`. but if you pass 0 in place `NumberOfBytesRead` you need use `GetOverlappedResult` for get it (or direct read `InternalHigh`). also how you think - from where `ReadFile` read and return to you `NumberOfBytesRead` ? of course from `overlapped` - simply no another way. we always can check iosb(call `GetOverlappedResult`) for any io

Comment: @RbMn. The article is clear, if we return synchronously DO NOT CALL GetOverlapped result, there is not guarantee that what comes back will be correct. It might or it might not.

Comment: i better know that :) my knowledge is more than enough in this area. or you wrong understand what is writed here or here writed error. we of course can call `GetOverlappedResult` in this case too and this will be absolute correct

Comment: try reply yourself on simply question - from where `ReadFile` get the `lpNumberOfBytesRead` ?